# ReSharper: How to apply [NotNull] or [CanBeNull] annotation implicitly with another attribute?

Tags: c#, resharper, static-analysis

In our code, we have our own injection framework to enable dependency injection, like:

```
public class MyClass {
    [Component("ComponentName1")] // means [NotNull]
    public MyType NotNullComponent{ get; set; }
    
    [OptionalComponent("ComponentName2")] // means [CanBeNull]
    public MyType CanBeNullComponent { get; set; }
}
```

We don't want to add `[CanBeNull]` or `[NotNull]` everywhere again since it has duplicated semantics to the `[Component]` and `[OptionalComponent]` attributes.

Is it possible to let ReSharper know the semantics of custom attributes to help static analysis?

Comment: Doesn't look like it's currently possible. I've raised an issue on ReSharper's youtrack here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-454461

Comment: @IgalTabachnik Thanks. It seems the quickest solution for now is to write our own Resharper plugin to support that.

Comment: Now available in resharper as an experimental feature.

Answer (score 0):

You now can implicitly use [NotNull] on everthing by enabling "Implicit" in Code Inspection -> Settings

Unless you specify [CanBeNull] everything will be assumed to not allow null.

[image]

Comment: That's not what I meant. I want Resharper to understand our custom attribute has the same semantic as NotNull or CanBeNull.

Comment: Could you extend their attribute?